# How to create a bootable usb of Ubuntu from a Lubuntu system

Tags: 12.04, usb, lubuntu

I am using Lubuntul  12.04 on my PC. I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop.

How do I create a bootable usb on Lubuntu so that I can install Ubuntu OS to my Laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Startup Disk creator.
Install via Software Center or:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

Comment: i can not install it, this is what appears. 'Package usb-creator-gtk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'usb-creator-gtk' has no installation candidate'

Comment: Ok. Then the program is not available at Lubuntu I think. You can use UNetbootin or otherwise try the solution below by Anton.

Comment: Worked for me. Lubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 2):

- open terminal and write this to find your usb: `sudo fdisk -l`
- write the iso to the usb `sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdx`
  where `/dev/sdx` corresponds to your usb.
- reboot and run from the usb to start
  installation!

Comment: this didn't work either!

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive discussion (on Kubuntu) here that you might find helpful:

[How do I make a bootable USB stick from an ISO image? I'm running Kubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181982/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-stick-from-an-iso-image-im-running-kubuntu-12-04)