# ISO to USB on Kubuntu

Tags: usb, 15.04, kubuntu, kde, iso

I'm running kubuntu 15.04 and I want to make bootable usb stick from an ISO file, how can I do that?
I tried this: [How do I make a bootable USB stick from an ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181982/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-stick-from-an-iso-image-im-running-kubuntu-12-04)
I also tried running UUI by wine (it didn't detect my usb stick)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use dd.

```
 sudo dd if=input.iso of=/dev/sdx
```

where  `input.iso` is the input file and `/dev/sdx` is the USB device you're writing to. This method is fast and has never failed me. **Note:** that the 'x' depends on the actual device the usb mounts as.

Comment: Actually, a few years ago I had some Ubuntu ISO which I didn't boot after I wrote it with dd to the USB device. Using some GUI programm it worked but I never found out what the problem was. So just as a hint: there might be some ISO files out there which do boot after writing them with dd to the usb device.

Answer (score 3):

Install unetbootin

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

1. plug in a USB drive
2. Delete all partitions on the USB drive
3. create a fat32 partition
4. mount the flash drive

open up a terminal and start unetbootin

```
sudo unetbootin
```

1. select disk image
2. choice you iso
3. select you flash drive
4. then click ok

[image]

wait for that to be done and you have your self a  bootable usb stick.

Comment: When booting from a Ubuntu 16.04 Server iso, it detected that it was created using unetbootin, and presented a warning during setup, to warn use of unetbootin is unreliable.

Comment: I have found unetbootin to be unreliable as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html)

Binaries:

[32bit](http://launchpad.net/unetbootin/trunk/613/+download/unetbootin-linux-613.bin)

[64bit](http://launchpad.net/unetbootin/trunk/613/+download/unetbootin-linux64-613.bin)

The PPA repository doesn't work (for me at least), so I don't post it.

Today I've tried it (for Kubuntu 15.10), but unsuccessfully. Please post your results afterwards.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have found `unetbootin` to be unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#3-launch-startup-disk-creator).

It should be preinstalled in both Ubuntu and Kubuntu.